# Unity audioclip (almost always) is not playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have WeaponController class and TeslaGunController and ShotGunController classes, inherited from it.
In WeaponController class I have methods Shoot() and Reload() which are setting audio clips to play:

```
protected virtual void Shoot()
    {
        audioSource.clip = audioShoot;
        audioSource.Play();
    }

protected void Reload()
    {
        if ((int)playerController.inventory[ammo] > 0)
        {
            audioSource.clip = audioReload;
            audioSource.Play();
            if ((int)playerController.inventory[ammo] + curCartridges >= magazine)
            {   
                playerController.inventory[ammo] = (int)playerController.inventory[ammo] - magazine + curCartridges;
                curCartridges = magazine;
            }
            else
            {
                curCartridges += (int)playerController.inventory[ammo];
                playerController.inventory[ammo] = 0;
            }
            reloadTime = 0;
        }
    }
```

It is working alright in ShotGunController

```
protected override void Shoot()
    {
        if (curTimeout > fireRate)
        {   
            barrelTransform = playerController.currentBarrelTransform;
            light2D = barrelTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<Light2D>();
            EnableLight();
            curTimeout = 0;

            mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            barrellPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(barrelTransform.position); 
            mousePos = (mousePos - barrellPos).normalized;

            secondPos = new Vector2(barrelTransform.position[0], barrelTransform.position[1] +  0.01f);
            firstPos = new Vector2(barrelTransform.position[0], barrelTransform.position[1] - 0.01f);

            Shoot_(firstPos, false);
            Shoot_(firstPos, true);
            Shoot_(secondPos, false);
            Shoot_(secondPos, true);

            curCartridges--;
            Invoke("DisableLight", 0.1f);
            base.Shoot();
        }
    }
protected override void Update()
    {
        reloadTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if(!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            curTimeout += Time.deltaTime;
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && curCartridges > 0 && reloadTime > 0.5f)
            Shoot();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
            Reload();
    }
```

But it almost does not works in TeslaGunController:

```
protected override void Shoot()
    {
        if (curTimeout > fireRate)
        {
            curTimeout = 0;
            barrelTransform = playerController.currentBarrelTransform;
            Draw();
            curCartridges--;
            base.Shoot();
        }
    }

protected override void Update()
    {
        reloadTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if(!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            curTimeout += Time.deltaTime;
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && curCartridges > 0)
            Shoot();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
            Reload();
    }
```

It does not even throw any errors,it just does not play except for some (I guess) random moments, although the methods in these two classes are pretty similar. I do not override Reload() method in any inherited class, no problems with any audioclip itself (due to its working in ShotGunController).
I have found that TeslaGunController calls base.Shoot() two times, while ShotGunController only once. I can not figure out why and why audioclips are not playing. 
What is possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.
I had two scripts added to TeslaGun gameobject. And the second one had none public audio clip attached.